# Vue 3 + vuex store is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I used Vue 3 cli to install new testing ground for store and router to learn those.

Project come like this :

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

store.js (just added count for testing):

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

and in views:
Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(store.state.count)
  },
};
</script>
```

By all that I have read I should be able to access store in component with:

```
mounted() {
        console.log(store.state.count)
      },
```

But i get store is not defined.
While it is obliviously imported and used in main app with index.js's:

```
import store from "./store";
    
    createApp(App).use(store)
```

I heave spent hours on this, please advise. This is out of the box cli installation, i don't understand what they wont me to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to access it using `this` and prepended by `$` sign:

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.count)
  },
};
```